# Bad formation on wrapfiure latex overlap image text

Tags: latex

[image]

I am using overleaf online to compile my report and I am experiencing this problem with wrap figure. particularly over a weight of 6cm I experience the problem as shown in figure, image overlaps the text while independent on the size of the image there is some text with a weird formation in the successive page. Can someone help me?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
  \usepackage{geometry}
     \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{graphicx,bm,times}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{gensymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{geometry}
  %\geometry{lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
   ...
   to suppress axial growth during GaInP shell growth, the nanowire cores were taken out from the reactor and the Au seed particles were removed using a cyanide based Au etchant. Shell growth was carried out in the same MOCVD as the core, using PH3, (TMIn), and TMGa as precursors gases.The shell growth temperature was set to 600 $\textdegree $C.

  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=7cm]{IMAGES/nanos1.png} 
%\caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:wrapfig}
\end{wrapfigure}
Transmission electron microscopy \textbf{TEM} and Electron Diffraction Spectroscopy \textbf{SEM} allow to investigate nanowires revealing its crystal structure: pure zinc blende, (without wurtzite segments, stacking faults, or twins).  Particularly high-resolution transmission electron microscopy showed dense fringes indicating significant strain (Fig A).
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could add an extra option to the wrapfigure command:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[22]{L}{0.45\textwidth}
```

where the '22' represents the number of lines you want to wrap around.

(Credit to [Jenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9530987/jenny) who answered on a comment!)

Answer (score 4):

Your image and text overlap because you specify your image width to be `6cm`, but you only allocate a wrapfigure width of `.25\textwidth`. Your warpfigure must be at least as wide as your figure.

Unrelated to your problem, but please

- don't load the same package multiple times.
- don't specify both the width and height of an image, this will distort the aspect ratio, you can see this with the duck picture I used below.
- the package `times` is obsolete, have a look at mathptmx, helvet or courier instead
- it is not necessary to specify the file extension of your image. In fact if you just use the name without extension, latex will automatically choose the one with the best quality in case there are multiple images with the same name
- you already load the `siunitx` package, please also use it to get correct spacing between numbers and units
- "the 1 ???m thick" looks as if there might be an encoding problem with your document. Please check if your file is really encoded in latin1 and not, say, utf8

---

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
  \usepackage{geometry}
     \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 %  \usepackage{amsmath}
 %\usepackage{amsfonts}
 %\usepackage{amssymb}
 %\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{graphicx,bm
%,times
}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 %\usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{gensymb}
 %\usepackage{amsmath}
 %\usepackage{geometry}
  %\geometry{lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}


\begin{document}
   to suppress axial growth during GaInP shell growth, the nanowire cores were taken out from the reactor and the Au seed particles were removed using a cyanide based Au etchant. Shell growth was carried out in the same MOCVD as the core, using PH3, (TMIn), and TMGa as precursors gases.The shell growth temperature was set to \SI{600}{\celsius}.
  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{6cm}
 \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=7cm]{example-image-duck} 
%\caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:wrapfig}
\end{wrapfigure}
Transmission electron microscopy \textbf{TEM} and Electron Diffraction Spectroscopy \textbf{SEM} allow to investigate nanowires revealing its crystal structure: pure zinc blende, (without wurtzite segments, stacking faults, or twins).  Particularly high-resolution transmission electron microscopy showed dense fringes indicating significant strain (Fig~A). 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, could tell how to solve the problem of the  text with a weird formation in the successive page?

Comment: @AndreaAngeletti The code fragment in your question does not reproduce the problem with text on the next page. Please make a [mre] that actually shows this problem.

Answer (score 3):

you could add an extra option to the wrapfigure command:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[22]{L}{0.45\textwidth}
```

where the '22' represents the number of lines you want to wrap around.